# Pandas loop using variables with different lengths

Tags: python, pandas, loops, iteration

I'm performing some time-series classification and I need to get the prediction voting output given the previous predictions up to some point. I have a lot of instances and I need loops to get my results.
I'm having difficulties creating a working a loop with variables of different lengths. I have a dataframe for each time-series data and they all have different lengths.

The first variable is the unique ID. for example trip0, and the other loop variable needs to be each time point in the dataframe, t0 , which could have hundreds of points. I need to match in one loop iteration trip0 and do some operation for each of the t0 values. And then do this for trip1 matched with t1 and so on until the operation is performed for each available trip_i's available.

I've gotten up to this point:

```
for time_elapsed in t0:
    trip = trip_0[trip_0['time_elapsed_s'] <= time_elapsed]
    voting_output_t =  trip['prediction_mode'].mode()[0]
    prediction_mode_t.append(voting_output_t)
```

In the code above, t0 contains time in minutes, such as 5,10,...,500. Trip_0 is the dataframe of that particular time-series instance and it also contains the t0 time values. Looking at that code I have to do this manually for each trip_i and t_i value because I haven't been able to create a working loop that uses variables of different lengths and does the operation for each existing value in the t_i variable that is longer in length. I've also tried some variations with zip and itertools without success.

Shortly: I need to create a loop that takes the dataframes trip_0, trip1 as one variable, and t_0, t_1 as another variable containing values for each row. The operations need to match in every loop iteration. So trip_0 needs to be matched with the values of t_0, trip_1 with the values of t_1, and so on.

Comment: If you can post a sample data set and expected result, you are more likely to get answers.